# WAS 6 to WAS 7 Migration Issues

Tags: java, enums, rad

I opened my WAS6 wrkspace in WAS7(RAD7). After using Auto migration tool i noticed many errors on enum.

A code snippet -

```
protected static Enum getBaseEnum(Class enumClass, String name) {
    Enum enum = null;

    enum = getEnum(enumClass, name);

    if (enum == null) {
        String enumList = StringUtils.join(getEnumList(enumClass).iterator(), ",");
        log.error("INVALID ENUM TYPE: " + name + " FOR CLASS: " + enumClass.getName() + ", VALID TYPES: " + enumList);            
    }

    return enum;
}
```

*How can I remove those errors*
*Enum cannot be resolved    AbstractEnum.java*

Comment: `enum` is a keyword in Java 5+

Comment: So how can I resolve error on it?

Comment: I doubt you can, without modifying the source code. Try compiling with Java Compiler Compliance set to 1.4

Comment: Got it ! Simply renamed enum to enum1

Comment: Cool, I didn't realise you had control over source code.